# Elevation in v-dialog vuetify vueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I would like to know how I could remove the elevation of a v-dialog, so that it is left with nothing, the `elevation` property in the v-dialog itself does not work, nor does it embed it using the class as `Class = "elevation-0"`

Link of the component: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#dialogs

this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust the elevation on the dialog component by targeting the content-class prop:

```
<v-dialog
  v-model="true"
  content-class="elevation-0"
/>
```

Comment: what worked for me is that instead of using a v-dialog I used a v-overlay and it no longer contains the elevation

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things but I did not get the expected result, I tried to override the `shadow-box` from the css, access the Sass variables use another dialog but I did not get results, what ended up helping me was to use the `<v-overlay>` component and end of matter